# How to get value from text string in PHP

Tags: php

I have the following string:

```
"{\"ttl\": null\054 \"card_id\": \"np\"}.DPSXmw.VApKpbKiEnEoRgwWblgt-nuewFg"
```

I can tidy this using strip slashes so it becomes:

```
"{"ttl": null, "card_id": "np"}.DPSXmw.VApKpbKiEnEoRgwWblgt-nuewFg"
```

I need to get the value where `np` is however I am unsure how to do this. Is it best to remove the trailing text and address it as JSON or am I best using another method?

the string in question does contain the wrapping " "

Current Code:

```
echo stripslashes($VCIDcookie); 

$string = stripslashes($VCIDcookie);

output of $string: "{"ttl": null54 "card_id": "np"}.DPSXmw.VApKpbKiEnEoRgwWblgt-nuewFg"

$string = explode('}', $string);

$json = json_decode($string[0] .'}');
echo $json->card_id;
```

Updated Code - I have used trim() to remove the wrapping quotation marks so the string doesn't have them but I am still not getting the `np` output:

```
$string = trim($VCIDcookie,'"');
$string = stripslashes($string);
echo $string;
$string = explode('}', $string);

$json = json_decode($string[0] .'}');
echo $json->card_id;
```

Comment: So you would need the output of `np`? Does that always have `"card_id": ` in front of it?

Comment: Hmm, does your data actually still contain quotes around the whole content? Or are you adding that to show the example?

Comment: Sorry it does contain the quotes around the content.

Answer (score 3):

Try this :

```
$string = '{"ttl": null, "card_id": "np"}.DPSXmw.VApKpbKiEnEoRgwWblgt-nuewFg';
$string = explode('.', $string);

$json = json_decode($string[0]);
echo $json->card_id;
```

**Care** : I suppose **ttl** or **card_id** don't have "." in their values.

Or, to avoid problems with "." :

```
$string = '{"ttl": null, "card_id": "np"}.DPSXmw.VApKpbKiEnEoRgwWblgt-nuewFg';
$string = explode('}', $string);

$json = json_decode($string[0] .'}');
echo $json->card_id;
```

Comment: bit of a mix-up with quotations there, I think

Comment: provided the data never has dots in it

Comment: Totally right :) I updated my answer to say it. You're reading my mind !

Comment: If it does, might have to explode on `}.` and then add the extra `}` back before json_decode. OR go down the route of regexhell lol.

Comment: You could get rid of the issue with the period by doing explode on `}.`, and then adding `}` back to the s tring before decoding.

Comment: Yes you are both right, I hesitated with this, but cleaner in this way. I update my answer.

Comment: Whilst testing either of those methods I am not getting anything returned. I have updated my question with the updated php as I have it.

Comment: @VincentDecaux any ideas?

Comment: Try to var_dump your variables, like `$string` after `explode` to watch if everything's ok. Use `return` instead of `echo` if you need to return the value.